# CSV to multidimensional array with ColdFusion

Tags: php, arrays, coldfusion, csv, multidimensional-array

I am trying to load a CSV file into an array using ColdFusion (version 7.0.2.142559).  Right now I am getting the following error:

> A scalar value of type coldfusion.runtime.Struct cannot be assigned to a 2-dimensional ColdFusion array.
>   A ColdFusion 2-dimensional array can only hold 1-dimensional ColdFusion arrays and Java List objects.

My CSV file is setup in this format:

```
a,b
c,d
e,f
```

This is my first go with ColdFusion so I probably have some simple syntax error that I just cannot see.  Code is below.

```
<!--- get the current full path of the current --->
<cfset currentPath = getCurrentTemplatePath()>
<cfset currentDirectory = getDirectoryFromPath(currentPath)>
<!--- get and read the CSV-TXT file --->
<cffile action="read" file="#currentDirectory#/smalltest.csv" variable="csvfile">
<!--- create a new array --->
<cfset array=ArrayNew(2)>
<!--- loop through the CSV-TXT file on line breaks and insert into database --->
<cfloop index="index" list="#csvfile#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#">

    <cfset array[#index#][1]=#listgetAt('#index#',1, ',')#>
    <cfset array[#index#][2]=#listgetAt('#index#',2, ',')#>

</cfloop>

<cfdump var=#array#>
```

**Bonus:**

On a side note it would save me a lot of time if there were some way to call upon a PHP file from within ColdFusion since I already have this entire script completed (this is just a small portion) in PHP.  I read about ColdFusion custom tags (the tag `<cf_php>` would work perfect for me) but admin says no, thus I must work with ColdFusion or find some way to render PHP through ColdFusion.  Frames, JavaScript, or the `<cfhttp>` tag are all things I *think* might work... if you have an idea let me know.

Comment: If you can explain what your existing PHP script does after loading the CSV array we can probably tell you whether it will be possible to call your PHP script from CF.

Comment: @Anthony the PHP script take the info from the CSV file and sorts it in a certain way (base on a variable passed in the URL) then outputs it to an HTML table.
@Henry `<cf_php>` seemed like a good idea, if my server supported custom tags, but that isn't the case.  Why else should I forget about `<cf_php>`>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I think you could simplify Henry's example even further using a one dimensional array and arrayAppend.

```
<cfset array=ArrayNew(1)>
<cfloop index="line" list="#csvfile#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#">
    <cfset arrayAppend(array, listToArray(line))>
</cfloop>
```

> **A scalar value of type
>   coldfusion.runtime.Struct cannot be
>   assigned to a 2-dimensional ColdFusion
>   array.**

FYI: The original code is mixing loop types. With `<cfloop list="..">` the `index` value is an element of the list like "a,b" (not a line number). Obviously "a,b" is not the expected numeric index, hence the error.

```
<!--- what the code is actually doing --->
<cfset array['a,b'][1]=#listgetAt('#index#',1, ',')#>
<cfset array['a,b'][2]=#listgetAt('#index#',2, ',')#>
<cfset array['c,d'][1]=#listgetAt('#index#',1, ',')#>
....
```

Having nothing to do with your error, none of those # signs are necessary. The code will work either way, but it is cleaner to write:

```
<cfset array[lineNum][1]= listgetAt( index, 1, ',')>
```

instead of

```
<cfset array['#lineNum#'][1]=#listgetAt('#index#',1, ',')#>
```

Comment: Thanks. Not quite a one-liner, but close ;-)

Comment: @Leigh @Henry both of your answers work great, thanks a lot. I see that misuse of `index` was my error, but I want to make sure I understand your answer correctly. The third line of your answer is copying all elements of the current line to the array, and since the default delimiter of `listToArray` is a comma two elements are read in instead of one. The process repeats until the end of the list has been reached. Is that correct?

Comment: @typoknig - Essentially, yes.

Comment: @Leigh @Henry after messing with this a bit more I found that both of your solutions have an unfortunate side effect.  If an element of the CSV file contains a comma then things get messed up :(  Do you guys have any other ideas?  Please keep in mind too that I need to sort this data once it has been loaded into the array, via ColdFusion or JavaScript.

Comment: @typoknig - That is going to be a problem in any language. Obviously the delimiter value should never be used in the data itself, because it makes it near impossible to identify. Are the values at least quoted?

Comment: @Leigh, yes, the values are quoted.  I should point out again that I already have this working in PHP and I do not have this issue.

Comment: @typoknig - What function are you using in php? listToArray() is like php explode() or java split(). They are generic and not designed for the csv format specifically (ie embedded commas and quotes). Try something like CSVtoArray cflib.org/udf/CSVtoArray.

Comment: @Leigh I am using `fgetcsv` and delimiting on a comma. I think ColdFusion does not handle CSV specifically like PHP does.  Since the PHP function `fgetcsv` is made specifically for CSV it is smart enough to know not to separate on commas between double quotes.

Comment: @typoknig - Yes, there is no specialized function for csv format. The nearest equivalent to fgetcsv is probably cfhttp (though it returns a query). For arrays, either use one of the existing udf's like http://www.bennadel.com/index.cfm?dax=blog:976.view OR any established java library. There are plenty out there. Since CF runs on java, you just drop a jar in your class path and you are ready to go.

Comment: @Leigh my problem is that I have very limited access to our servers, so I cannot implement the simple changes (like adding a file to the class path) that would make my life easier. Our Information Services department handles everything web related, and beyond being glacial, they don't like to implement any changes because everything is "working" the way it is now. Anyways I finally found a way to get PHP to work in a `.cfm` file.  I just called the PHP from a script tag in the `.cfm` file and made the PHP script echo back the JavaScript required to make an `<iFrame>`. Messy but it works.

Comment: @typoknig - I hear you. Well you could still use the udf in the first link. It is pure CF code, so no jars needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfset array=ArrayNew(2)>
<cfset lineNum=1>
<cfloop index="line" list="#csvfile#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#">
    <cfset array[lineNum] = listToArray(line)>
    <cfset lineNum = lineNum + 1>
</cfloop>
```