# How to import/read data from csv (comma separated) file in coldfusion

Tags: csv, coldfusion

How to read data from comma separated file (.csv file) in coldfusion? i have to read contact details from csv file and insert it into database.

Thanks,
Yugal

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSV to multidimensional array with ColdFusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240018/csv-to-multidimensional-array-with-coldfusion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or if you're on CF8 you could use the UDF from [this blog post here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/991-csvtoarray-coldfusion-udf-for-parsing-csv-data-files.htm).

The code from that blog post is as follows:

```
<cffunction
  name="CSVToArray"
  access="public"
  returntype="array"
  output="false"
  hint="Takes a CSV file or CSV data value and converts it to an array of arrays based on the given field delimiter. Line delimiter is assumed to be new line / carriage return related.">

  <!--- Define arguments. --->
  <cfargument
    name="File"
    type="string"
    required="false"
    default=""
    hint="The optional file containing the CSV data."
    />

  <cfargument
    name="CSV"
    type="string"
    required="false"
    default=""
    hint="The CSV text data (if the file was not used)."
    />

  <cfargument
    name="Delimiter"
    type="string"
    required="false"
    default=","
    hint="The data field delimiter."
    />

  <cfargument
    name="Trim"
    type="boolean"
    required="false"
    default="true"
    hint="Flags whether or not to trim the END of the file for line breaks and carriage returns."
    />


  <!--- Define the local scope. --->
  <cfset var LOCAL = StructNew() />


  <!---
    Check to see if we are using a CSV File. If so,
    then all we want to do is move the file data into
    the CSV variable. That way, the rest of the algorithm
    can be uniform.
  --->
  <cfif Len( ARGUMENTS.File )>

    <!--- Read the file into Data. --->
    <cffile
      action="read"
      file="#ARGUMENTS.File#"
      variable="ARGUMENTS.CSV"
      />

  </cfif>


  <!---
    ASSERT: At this point, no matter how the data was
    passed in, we now have it in the CSV variable.
  --->

  <!---
    Check to see if we need to trim the data. Be default,
    we are going to pull off any new line and carraige
    returns that are at the end of the file (we do NOT want
    to strip spaces or tabs).
  --->
  <cfif ARGUMENTS.Trim>

    <!--- Remove trailing returns. --->
    <cfset ARGUMENTS.CSV = REReplace(
      ARGUMENTS.CSV,
      "[\r\n]+$",
      "",
      "ALL"
      ) />

  </cfif>

  <!--- Make sure the delimiter is just one character. --->
  <cfif (Len( ARGUMENTS.Delimiter ) NEQ 1)>

    <!--- Set the default delimiter value. --->
    <cfset ARGUMENTS.Delimiter = "," />

  </cfif>

  <!---
    Create a compiled Java regular expression pattern object
    for the expression that will be needed to parse the
    CSV tokens including the field values as well as any
    delimiters along the way.
  --->
  <cfset LOCAL.Pattern = CreateObject(
    "java",
    "java.util.regex.Pattern"
    ).Compile(
      JavaCast(
        "string",
        <!--- Delimiter. --->
        "\G(\#ARGUMENTS.Delimiter#|\r?\n|\r|^)" &
        <!--- Quoted field value. --->
        "(?:""([^""]*+(?>""""[^""]*+)*)""|" &
        <!--- Standard field value --->
        "([^""\#ARGUMENTS.Delimiter#\r\n]*+))"
        )
      )
    />

  <!---
    Get the pattern matcher for our target text (the
    CSV data). This will allows us to iterate over all the
    tokens in the CSV data for individual evaluation.
  --->
  <cfset LOCAL.Matcher = LOCAL.Pattern.Matcher(
    JavaCast( "string", ARGUMENTS.CSV )
    ) />


  <!---
    Create an array to hold the CSV data. We are going
    to create an array of arrays in which each nested
    array represents a row in the CSV data file.
  --->
  <cfset LOCAL.Data = ArrayNew( 1 ) />

  <!--- Start off with a new array for the new data. --->
  <cfset ArrayAppend( LOCAL.Data, ArrayNew( 1 ) ) />


  <!---
    Here's where the magic is taking place; we are going
    to use the Java pattern matcher to iterate over each
    of the CSV data fields using the regular expression
    we defined above.
    Each match will have at least the field value and
    possibly an optional trailing delimiter.
  --->
  <cfloop condition="LOCAL.Matcher.Find()">

    <!---
      Get the delimiter. We know that the delimiter will
      always be matched, but in the case that it matched
      the START expression, it will not have a length.
    --->
    <cfset LOCAL.Delimiter = LOCAL.Matcher.Group(
      JavaCast( "int", 1 )
      ) />


    <!---
      Check for delimiter length and is not the field
      delimiter. This is the only time we ever need to
      perform an action (adding a new line array). We
      need to check the length because it might be the
      START STRING match which is empty.
    --->
    <cfif (
      Len( LOCAL.Delimiter ) AND
      (LOCAL.Delimiter NEQ ARGUMENTS.Delimiter)
      )>

      <!--- Start new row data array. --->
      <cfset ArrayAppend(
        LOCAL.Data,
        ArrayNew( 1 )
        ) />

    </cfif>


    <!---
      Get the field token value in group 2 (which may
      not exist if the field value was not qualified.
    --->
    <cfset LOCAL.Value = LOCAL.Matcher.Group(
      JavaCast( "int", 2 )
      ) />

    <!---
      Check to see if the value exists. If it doesn't
      exist, then we want the non-qualified field. If
      it does exist, then we want to replace any escaped
      embedded quotes.
    --->
    <cfif StructKeyExists( LOCAL, "Value" )>

      <!---
        Replace escpaed quotes with an unescaped double
        quote. No need to perform regex for this.
      --->
      <cfset LOCAL.Value = Replace(
        LOCAL.Value,
        """""",
        """",
        "all"
        ) />

    <cfelse>

      <!---
        No qualified field value was found, so use group
        3 - the non-qualified alternative.
      --->
      <cfset LOCAL.Value = LOCAL.Matcher.Group(
        JavaCast( "int", 3 )
        ) />

    </cfif>


    <!--- Add the field value to the row array. --->
    <cfset ArrayAppend(
      LOCAL.Data[ ArrayLen( LOCAL.Data ) ],
      LOCAL.Value
      ) />

  </cfloop>


  <!---
    At this point, our array should contain the parsed
    contents of the CSV value. Return the array.
  --->
  <cfreturn LOCAL.Data />
</cffunction>
```